# Verifying firebase custom token with public key doen't work

Tags: java, spring, firebase, jwt

Server side, i'm creating a [custom tokens using a third-party JWT library](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library)

I'm using the private key token from the service account JSON file to sign the JWT.

I want to  [verify the token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library) with the public keys provided by firebase (that we also find in the account JSON file)

My question is that firebase is providing public certificate like these [exemples](https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com). I'm having problems using them since the jwt.io is always displaying 'not Verified'. 
NB: I'm using Java in the backend and i don't want to use firebase service account ID.